# Методы equals и hashcode

Tags: java, объекты

```
    BlackBox object1 = new BlackBox(5, 10);
    BlackBox object2 = new BlackBox(5, 10);


    System.out.println(object1.hashCode());
    System.out.println(object2.hashCode());
    System.out.println(object1.equals(object2));

1956725890
356573597
false
```

Из статьи на хабре: если объекты одинаковые, то и хеш-коды одинаковые (но не наоборот, см. правило 3)

Почему в вышеприведенном примере хеш-коды разные? Почему `equals()` возвращает `false`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> если объекты одинаковые, то и хеш-коды одинаковые

Это правильное утверждение, только трактуете вы его неверно. Это ваша задача как программиста сделать так, чтобы хешкоды у одинаковых объектов были одинаковы (меру одинаковости выбираете и контролируете вы). Так как нельзя заранее определить, какие объекты будут равны, по умолчанию хешкодом является, емнип, указатель на объект, и в этом случае объект будет равен только себе самому. Чтобы изменить это поведение, вам нужно переопределить методы `.hashcode()` и `.equals()`.

Comment: Утверждение, что hashCode является значением указателя на объект не верно: https://habrahabr.ru/post/168195/ это просто рандомное число.

Comment: @Vartlok As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Comment: окей, не всегда верно. В OpenJDK это рандомное число.

Comment: @Vartlok http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l555 добрая половина методов таки использует указатель.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите сравнивать объекты собственного класса вам необходимо переопределить свойство equal() в вашем классе.

Answer (score -3):

Загляните под капот. Советую прочитать Рихтер  CLR via C# стр. 172.

Ссылки и будут разными, так как это два разных объекта.

```
BlackBox object1 = new BlackBox(5, 10);
BlackBox object2 = object1;


System.out.println(object1.hashCode());
System.out.println(object2.hashCode());
System.out.println(object1.equals(object2));
```