# Как выполнить правильное преобразование строки в дату?

Tags: java, строки, дата, преобразование

Добрый день,читаю из файла строку следующего вида,пытаюсь преобразовать в тип Date. Не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

```
String dat ="Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
        simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        Date birthDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dat);
```

Выкидывает вот такую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984" at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

Comment: Уточните что не получается. Выкидывает ошибку, не компилируется или полученная дата отлична от ожидаемой?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

Comment: А если так: `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`?

Comment: Наверное глупый вопрос,а почему второй параметр обязателен?

Comment: Вопрос нормальный) Видимо потому, что у вас локаль системы русская, а локаль строки с датой - англо-саксонская.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,а можете продублировать как ответ,чтобы я вопрос закрыл.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста) А ответы и так есть, зачем лишние сущности плодить)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все дело в [локали](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
String dat ="Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date birthDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dat);
```

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте так:

```
String str = "Sat Jan 03 19:47:23 MSK 1984";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(str);
```

Как правильно сказали StateItPrimitive и ЮрийСПб, парсинг даты происходит с учётом локали.

Comment: Может быть _StateItPrimitive_ и правильно сказал, но, кажется, вы ответили на 2 секунды раньше (в течение первой минуты писались секунды)! :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, а мой коммент был ещё на 10 секунд раньше вашего ответа)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, косяк, на комментарии не посмотрел :(

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, не страшно) Я в коммент писал, т.к. не был уверен, что дело точно в локали)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме вышеперечисленного еще можно добавить, что есть метод ParseExact, который анализирует строку согласно некоторого шаблона

Comment: обратите внимание на метки вопроса, тут и [в другом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494094/190934) java, а не c#