# Как работает оператор проверки на равенство (оператор ==)

Tags: java, android

Как работает оператор проверки на равенство (оператор `==`)?

Имеются ли ему альтернативы?

Если альтернативы имеются, то в каких ситуациях следует их применять?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Оператор `==`**

В Java оператор `==` возвращает значение типа `boolean` - результат сравнения экземпляров объектов, либо примитивов. Поведение операции сравнения зависит от типов её операндов (объектных, либо примитивных типов).

---

**Сравнение объектов**

Если оба операнда являются экземплярами объектных типов, то данный оператор просто проверяет равенство ссылок (указывают ли ссылки, значения которых хранятся в сравниваемых переменных, на один и тот-же объект в Heap'е), а ***не сравнивает на равенство внутреннее содержимое объектов***.

Таким образом, при сравнении объектов в Java оператор `==` вернет `true` лишь в том случае, когда ссылки указывают на один и тот-же объект из heap (кучи).

*Контрольный пример:*

```
Integer integer1 = new Integer(1);
Integer integer2 = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(integer1 == integer2); // false

integer2 = integer1;
System.out.println(integer1 == integer2); // true
```

---

**Сравнение примитивов**

Сравнение примитивных типов происходит в следующих ситуациях:

1. оба операнда являются экземплярами примитивных типов (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, либо `double`);
2. если хотя бы один из операндов являются экземпляром примитивного типа (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, либо `double`), а второй является экземпляром объектного типа обертки (*Wrapper Class*) над примитивным (`Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Character`, `Float`, либо `Double`), то отработает механизм [autounboxing](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1948-objertki-raspakovka-i-zapakovka) (у экземпляра объектного типа будет вызван соответствующий этому типу метод: `byteValue()`, `shortValue()`, `intValue()`, `longValue()`, `charValue()`, `floatValue()`, либо `doubleValue()`), после чего мы получаем два экземпляра примитивных типов (возможно, разных - см. следующий абзац, подробнее см. [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).

*Алгоритм сравнения:*

Сначала операнды распространяются (т.е. происходит "арифметическое распространение ([promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) операндов") до наибольшего, если это необходимо (если операнды являются экземплярами разных примитивных типов), а затем происходит непосредственное побитовое сравнение (если все биты равны, то возвращаемое значение будет `true`, иначе - `false`).

*Контрольный пример:*

Например, значение `48.0f` (типа `float`, соответственно) равно значению `'0'` (код которого равен `48` согласно таблице символов Unicode) типа `char`, значение которого неявно распространяется до типа `float`.

```
char char1 = '0';
int int1 = 48;
float float1 = 48.0F;
Integer integer1 = 48; // произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(48);
System.out.println(char1 == int1);    // true
System.out.println(char1 == float1);  // true
System.out.println(int1 == float1);   // true
System.out.println(int1 == integer1); // true (произойдет вызов: integer1.intValue();)

// ---------------------------------------------

char char2 = 'A';
long long2 = 65L;
float float2 = 65.0F;
Long longInteger2 = 65L; // произойдет вызов: Long.valueOf(65L);
System.out.println(char2 == long2);        // true
System.out.println(char2 == float2);       // true
System.out.println(long2 == float2);       // true
System.out.println(long2 == longInteger2); // true (произойдет вызов: longInteger2.longValue();)
```

---

**Сравнение вещественных примитивов**

Для вещественных примитивов (`float` и `double`) существуют некоторые особенности, которые необходимо учитывать. Представление вещественных чисел в Java соответствует [стандарту IEEE 754](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/), т.е. число представлено в виде *мантисы* (значимой части) и *порядка* (степени, в которую возводится основание/база системы) откуда следует то, что как целая, так и дробная часть числа представлены с помощью конечного числового ряда `2^(n)`, где как максимальное, так и минимальное значение числа `n` зависят от размера мантисы и порядка, которые, в свою очередь, зависят от конкретного типа (`float`, `double`). Как следствие, о точном представлении произвольно взятого числа говорить не приходится.

*Контрольный пример:*

Примеры представления чисел с плавающей точкой в памяти машины согласно [стандарту IEEE 754](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/) можно найти [здесь](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/index.xhtml).

Само собой разумеется, что две вещественные переменные, проинициализированные одним и тем же вещественным литералом, будут равны (ведь они проинициализировались одной и той же последовательностью бит):

```
float float1 = 0.7F;
float float2 = 0.7F;

System.out.println(float1 == float2); // true
```

Но стоит начать выполнять арифметические операции с переменными данного типа, как, скорее всего, начнет накапливаться погрешность вычислений (из-за указанных выше особенностей представления экземпляров данного типа):

```
float float1 = 0.7F;
float float2 = 0.3F + 0.4F;

System.out.println(float1 == float2); // false
System.out.println(float1);           // 0.7
System.out.println(float2);           // 0.70000005
```

*Контрольный пример представления нецелых чисел:*

Например, число `1/10` нельзя точно представить в виде суммы отрицательных степеней числа два, в отличие от некоторых других чисел:

1. `0.25` = `2^(-2)`;
2. `0.5` = `2^(-1)`;
3. `0.75` = `2^(-1)` + `2^(-2)`;
4. и так далее.

*Контрольный пример представления целых чисел:*

Так как числа с плавающей точкой представлены согласно [стандарту IEEE 754](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/), то на примере чисел с одинарной точностью представления (т.е. `float`) можно понять, что не смотря на то, что посредством данного типа можно хранить невероятно большие числа, точность хранения младшей части числа (младших бит) сильно ограничена.

Рассмотрим диапазоны значений типов с одинаковой размерностью (4 байта):

- `int`: `[-2^31, 2^(31) - 1] ≈ [-2 * 10^(9), 2 * 10^(9)]`;
- `float`: `[-3.4028235 * 10^(38), 3.4028235 * 10^(38)]`.

Такая невероятная разница в диапазоне хранимых целых значений возникает из-за точности хранения:

- `int` хранит целые числа с абсолютной точностью, т.к. из 32 бит лишь 1 бит используется для определения знака числа, а остальные 31 для непосредственного кодирования его значения;
- `float` с абсолютной точностью может хранить лишь 24 бита (23 бита мантисы + 1 зарезервированный бит), а остальные 9 (= 32 - 23) битов используются для определения порядка (8 бит) и знака числа (1 бит).

Из этого следует, что если между старшим и младшим битом более 24 бит (включая их самих), то вся та часть, что не умещается в 24 старших бита будет выкинута:

```
System.out.println("int:");
int int_24bit = 0b0000_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001;
int int_25bit = 0b0001_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001;
System.out.println("24 битное целое число: " + int_24bit);
System.out.println("25 битное целое число: " + int_25bit);
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 1 (0b0001): " + (int_25bit += 0b0001));
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 2 (0b0010): " + (int_25bit += 0b0010));
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 3 (0b0011): " + (int_25bit += 0b0011));

System.out.println("\nfloat:");
float float_24bit = 0b0000_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001;
float float_25bit = 0b0001_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001;
System.out.println("24 битное целое число: " + (int) float_24bit);
System.out.println("25 битное целое число: " + (int) float_25bit);
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 1 (0b0001): " + (int) (float_25bit += 0b0001));
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 2 (0b0010): " + (int) (float_25bit += 0b0010));
System.out.println("25 битное целое число + 3 (0b0011): " + (int) (float_25bit += 0b0011));
```

Полный вывод программы с пояснениями:

```
int:
24 битное целое число: 8388609
25 битное целое число: 16777217
25 битное целое число + 1 (0b0001): 16777218
25 битное целое число + 2 (0b0010): 16777220
25 битное целое число + 3 (0b0011): 16777223

float:
24 битное целое число: 8388609
25 битное целое число: 16777216 // 25-ый (младший) бит был проигнорирован, т.е. были взяты 24 старших бита (мантиса) и учтена степень их сдвига влево (порядок)
25 битное целое число + 1 (0b0001): 16777216 // 25-ый (младший) бит был проигнорирован, т.е. значение числа не изменилось
25 битное целое число + 2 (0b0010): 16777218 // число уместилось в 24 бита, т.е. значение увеличилось на 2
25 битное целое число + 3 (0b0011): 16777220 // 25-ый (младший) бит был проигнорирован, т.е. значение числа увеличилось лишь 2, а не на 3
```

Примечания:

- Для упрощения восприятия в примере выше я использовал целые числа, но стоит понимать, что это касается и дробной части, т.е. если расстояние между старшим и младшим битом более 24 битов, то все, что после 24 бита не будет сохранено (причем, старший бит может быть как составляющей целой, так и дробной части числа).
- Точно такие же эффекты наблюдаются и для типа с двойной точностью хранения (`double`), но уже с иной размерностью: 52 битов мантиса (+ 1 зарезервированный), 11 битов порядок и 1 знаковый бит. Таким образом, для потери точности хранения в рамках типа `double` потребуется число, в двоичном представлении которого между младшим и старшим битом расстояние превышает 53 битов (включая их самих).
- Вследствие наличия данного эффекта в высшей математике для подсчета более точной суммы ряда сначала суммируются наименьшие значения, а затем результат суммируются с большими значениями, т.е. сначала происходит наращивание значений из младших бит в более старшие. Такие действия выполняются итаративно над группами значений n раз. Количество групп значений, как следствие и итераций, зависит от разницы в значениях на определенной группе чисел.

**Как следует сравнивать вещественные примитивы**

Вещественные примитивы (`float` и `double`) стоит сравнивать с определенной точностью. Например, округлять их до 6-го знака после запятой (`1E-6` для `double`, либо `1E-6F` для `float`), либо, что предпочтительнее, проверять абсолютное значение разницы между ними.

*Контрольный пример:*

```
float float1 = 0.7F;
float float2 = 0.3F + 0.4F;
final float EPS = 1E-6F;

System.out.println(Math.abs(float1 - float2) < EPS); // true
```

Стоит понимать, что существуют и [другие](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) более точные, но при этом куда более изощренные варианты сравнения чисел с плавающей точкой.

---

**Использование Pool'ов**

Как уже было сказано выше, оператор `==` проверяет указывают ли ссылки на один и тот же объект, но иногда под этим простым выражением скрывается нечто большее, чем может показаться на первый взгляд.

Для более эффективного использования памяти, в Java используются так называемые пулы (`Boolean`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long` и `String`). Когда мы создаем объект, не используя оператор `new` (посредством литералов, либо с использованием механизма [autoboxing](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1948-objertki-raspakovka-i-zapakovka)), объект помещается в пул, и в последствии, если мы захотим создать такой же объект (опять же, без используя оператора `new`), то новый объект создан не будет, а мы просто получим ссылку на наш объект из пула, т.е. по факту один и тот же объект будет переиспользован в нескольких местах (такое поведение допустимо для объектов вышеописанных типов, т.к. они являются *immutable*).

*Примечание:*

Стоит заметить, что использование любого Pool'а за исключением `String` будет осуществляться при любой автоупаковке (если, конечно, значение соответсвует определенному диапазону, зависящему от типа, см. [autoboxing](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1948-objertki-raspakovka-i-zapakovka)). В случае же Pool'а `String` интернирование (`intern`) работает только для литералов.

---

**Boolean pool**

`Boolean` pool хранит оба возможных значения, т.е. объектные Wrapper'ы для обоих примитивов (`true` и `false`).

*Контрольный пример:*

```
Boolean valueFromPool1 = true; // произойдет вызов: Boolean.valueOf(true);
Boolean valueFromPool2 = true; // произойдет вызов: Boolean.valueOf(true);

System.out.println(valueFromPool1 == valueFromPool2); // true
System.out.println(true == valueFromPool1);           // true (произойдет вызов: valueFromPool1.booleanValue();)
System.out.println((Boolean) true == valueFromPool1); // true (произойдет вызов: Boolean.valueOf(true);)
```

**Short / Integer / Long pool**

Особенность целочисленных (`Short`, `Integer` и `Long`) pool'ов состоит в том, что, по умолчанию, они хранят только числа, которые помещаются в тип данных `byte`, т.е. числа в интервале от `-128` до `127` (который начиная с Java 7 (раньше это было захардкожено внутри классов `java.lang.Short`, `java.lang.Integer` и `java.lang.Long`, соответственно) можно расширить с помощью опции *JVM*, пример для `Integer`: `-Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=size` или `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=size`). Для остальных чисел данных типов pool не работает.

*Почему отсутствуют Float и Double pool:*

Для чисел с плавающей точкой (`Float`, `Double`) отсутствуют специфичные pool'ы вследствие особенностей хранения таких чисел согласно [стандарту IEEE 754](https://habr.com/ru/post/112953/). Использование для них pool'ов оказалось бы крайне неэффективно (хотя бы, в виду огромного количества чисел с плавающей точкой, находящихся в интервале от `-128.0` до `127.0`).

*Контрольный пример:*

```
Integer valueFromPool1 = 127;    // произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(127);
Integer valueFromPool2 = 127;    // произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(127);
Integer valueNotFromPool1 = 128; // произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(128);
Integer valueNotFromPool2 = 128; // произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(128);

System.out.println(valueFromPool1 == valueFromPool2);       // true
System.out.println(valueNotFromPool1 == valueNotFromPool2); // false

System.out.println(127 == valueFromPool1);              // true  (произойдет вызов: valueFromPool1.intValue();)
System.out.println(128 == valueNotFromPool1);           // true  (произойдет вызов: valueNotFromPool1.intValue();)
System.out.println((Integer) 127 == valueFromPool1);    // true  (произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(127);)
System.out.println((Integer) 128 == valueNotFromPool1); // false (произойдет вызов: Integer.valueOf(128);)
```

---

**String pool**

Выделим основные нюансы строкового пула в Java:

1. строковые литералы (в одном/разных классе(ах) и в одном/разных пакете(ах)) представляют собой ссылки на один и тот же объект;
2. строки, получающиеся сложением констант, вычисляются во время компиляции и далее смотри пункт первый;
3. строки, создаваемые во время выполнения НЕ ссылаются на один и тот же объект;
4. метод `intern()`, в любом случае, возвращает объект из пула, вне зависимости от того, когда создается строка, на этапе компиляции или выполнения (если на этапе выполнения, то объект сначала принудительно разместится в pool, а затем на него будет получена ссылка).

В контексте данных пунктов речь шла об "одинаковых" строковых литералах.

*Контрольный пример:*

```
String hello = "Hello", hello2 = "Hello";
String hel = "Hel", lo = "lo";

System.out.println("Hello" == "Hello");           // true
System.out.println("Hello" == "hello");           // false
System.out.println(hello == hello2);              // true
System.out.println(hello == ("Hel" + "lo"));      // true
System.out.println(hello == (hel + lo));          // false
System.out.println(hello == (hel + lo).intern()); // true
```

Подробнее про *interning* можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417843/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-interning-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), а про сравнивание строк [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417406/200756).

---

**Альтерантивы оператору `==`**

Для сравнения двух экземпляров объектных типов в Java также существуют такие методы как: `equals()` и `hashCode()`. Методы `hashCode()` и `equals()` определены в классе `java.lang.Object`, который является родительским классом для объектов Java, поэтому все Java-объекты наследуют от этих методов реализацию по умолчанию.

**Использование equals() и hashCode()**

Метод `equals()`, как и следует из его названия, используется для простой проверки равенства двух объектов. Реализация этого метода, по умолчанию, проверяет равенство ссылок двух объектов, т.е. по умолчанию, поведение идентично работе оператора `==` за исключением того, что оператор `==` не позволяет сравнивать операнды неприводимых друг к другу типов.

Метод `hashCode()` обычно используется для получения уникального целого числа, что на самом деле не является правдой, т.к. результат работы данного метода - это целое число примитивного типа `int` (называемое *хеш-кодом*), полученное посредством работы *хэш-функции* входным параметром которой является объект, вызывающий данный метод, но множество возможных *хеш-кодов* ограничено примитивным типом `int` (всего `2^32` вариантов значений), а множество объектов ограничено только нашей фантазией.

Из вышеописанного между методами `hashCode()` и `equals()` следует следующий контракт:

- если хеш-коды разные, то и объекты гарантированно разные;
- если хеш-коды равны, то входные объекты могут быть неравны (это обусловленно тем, что *множество объектов мощнее множества хеш-кодод*, т.к. множество возможных хеш-кодов ограничено размером примитивного типа `int`).

Подробнее про данные методы можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493576/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-equals-%D0%B8-hashcode).

**Переопределение поведения по умолчанию**

Так как в Java отсутствует возможность переопределять операторы (т.е. поведеие оператора `==` не может быть изменено) как, например, в *C++* или *C#*, то для сравнения двух объектов определенных классов согласно необходимому для вас алгоритму можно переопределить (`@Override`) методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` внутри нашего класса и использовать их.

Таким образом, создавая пользовательский класс следует переопределять методы `hashCode()` и `equals()`, чтобы они корректно работали и учитывали необходимые для вас данные (поля) объекта. Кроме того, если не переопределить реализацию из `Object`, то, например, при использовании таких объектов в `java.util.HashMap` у вас наверняка возникнут проблемы, поскольку `HashMap` активно использует `hashCode()` и `equals()` в своей работе (подробнее см. [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/168195/)).

---

**Особенности при работе с вещественными типами `Float` и `Double`**

В Java `NaN`'ы несравнимы между собой, но есть два исключения в работе классов `Float` и `Double`, рассмотрим на примере класса `Float`:

1. Если `float1` и `float2` оба представляют `Float.NaN`, тогда метод `equals` возвращает `true`, в то время как `Float.NaN == Float.NaN` принимает значение `false`.
2. Если `float1` содержит `+0.0f` в то время как `float2` содержит `-0.0f`, метод `equals` возвращает `false`, в то время как `0.0f == -0.0f` возвращает `true`.

*Контрольный пример 1:*

```
Float float1 = new Float(Float.NaN);
Float float2 = new Float(Float.NaN);

System.out.println(float1 == float2);       // false
System.out.println(float1.equals(float2));  // true
System.out.println(Float.NaN == Float.NaN); // false

// --------------------------------------------------

Double double1 = new Double(Double.NaN);
Double double2 = new Double(Double.NaN);

System.out.println(double1 == double2);       // false
System.out.println(double1.equals(double2));  // true
System.out.println(Double.NaN == Double.NaN); // false
```

*Контрольный пример 2:*

```
Float float1 = new Float(0.0F);
Float float2 = new Float(-0.0F);

System.out.println(float1 == float2);      // false
System.out.println(float1.equals(float2)); // false
System.out.println(0.0F == -0.0F);         // true

// --------------------------------------------------

Double double1 = new Double(0.0);
Double double2 = new Double(-0.0);

System.out.println(double1 == double2);      // false
System.out.println(double1.equals(double2)); // false
System.out.println(0.0 == -0.0);             // true
```

---

**Подведем итоги**

Если вам необходимо проверить не ссылаются ли две переменных на один и тот же объект, либо сравнить на равенство два примитива, то вам определенно стоит воспользоваться оператором `==` (при этом стоит иметь в виду то, что вещественные числа следует сравнить лишь с определенной точностью), но если же вам необходимо сравнить именно внутреннее содержимое объектов (либо основываясь на каком-нибудь нестандартном алгоритме), на которые ссылаются данные переменные, то вам стоит воспользоваться методом `equals()` соответствующего класса (причем если вы в своем классе переопределяете метод `equals()`, то при этом вам также стоит не забыть переопределить метод `hashCode()` согласно вышеописанному контракту между ними).

Comment: волшебно, не хватает разве что пару строк про примитивы

Comment: Добавлю, что использование кэша Integer будет осуществляться при любой автоупаковке, если значение соответсвует указанному диапазону (в отличии от строк, для которых интернирование работает для литералов). Также этот диапазон можно регулировать опцией -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax.

Comment: Ваш ответ — неформат для СО. Использовать ваш ответ как цель для закрытия вопросов как дубликатов неудобно, потому что это всё равно что отправлять читать документацию: вместо решения конкретной проблемы вы заставляете читать многобукаф, всё размазано. Текст клёвый, конечно, но это статья, а не ответ. Вы решаете проблему, которая не существует. Например, у кого вообще возникает проблема со сравнением char и float в реальной жизни? Это из разряда "блеснуть знаниями перед приятелями", причём даже без толкового объяснения. Та же проблема с остальными кусками ответа — непроработанные объяснения.

Comment: @Discord Понимаю, и я даже согласен. Изначально все так и задумывалось - лаконично разъяснить все, но в ходе написания стали всплывать особенности одна за другой. Ну, а затем стало жалко удалять то, что уже накопилось.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Попробуйте запостить на хабр что ли. :) И давайте подходить рационально: вопрос про строки уже есть (в принципе нормальный, но про пул сказано мало — ориентация на новичков), вопрос про числа с плавающей точкой тоже есть (внеязыковой, более подробный), а вот про пулы ничего нет, вроде. Соответственно, я бы переработал вопрос про пул чисел в нечто самостоятельное, и неплохо бы начать с постановки проблемы (не знаю, как в джаве, а в шарпе "проблема" со сравнением чисел по ссылке возникает только на собеседованиях).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Информацию про пул строк можно поместить как дополнительный ответ в вопросе про сравнение строк, там это будет уместно, потому что пул описан очень поверхностно. По пулу строк у вас описание отличное, подробное. Вопрос уже использовался для закрытия дубликатов, то есть уже имеются входящие ссылки, там ваш ответ будет легко найти.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Что делать со сравнением 48.0f == '0' — без понятия. Как по мне, бесполезная информация. Можно поместить в отдельный QA, причём желательно с разбором, что будет в случае 48.5f (из вашего примера мне не понятно, что и как именно сравнивается).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Пометки "как подсказывают в комментариях" следует удалить, опцинально вместе со скобками, это мусорный текст. Ужас про "используется для получения уникального целого числа, хотя на самом деле не совсем уникального" я бы удалил без сожаления. Названия язков программирования — не `код`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Про хэшкоды по-хорошему нужно написать что-то отдельное. То, что сейчас есть в этом ответе — какое-то поверхностное описание, а не решение проблемы или вводный текст, то есть бесполезно. Правильной была бы постановка вопроса в духе "Почему объекты как-то неправильно запихиваются в хэшмапу?" или "Почему важно переопределять equals и hashCode вместе?" Отсюда уже можно было бы плясать: если есть проблема и решение, то это уже формат.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Оказывается, вопрос про interning (и, соответственно, про пул строк) уже есть. Если вам есть, что добавить, то стоит запостить как отдельный ответ там.

Comment: "Стоит заметить, что если объект методом которого вызывается equals(), равен null, то будет сгенерировано исключение NullPointerException)." Это стандартное поведение для любых null-объектов при вызове любого метода. Мне кажется стоит удалить часть лишней информации и  привести ссылки на ответы про интернирование, методы `equals()/hashCode()`.

Comment: _"значению '0' (... 48 ...) типа byte"_ - сильно сомневаюсь, что byte. Вероятно, int или short. Но юникодный '0' в 1 байт неявно не должен каститься.

Comment: _"значение переменной типа `byte`"_ - нет, оно типа `char`, а не `byte`.

Comment: @Qwertiy А вот это уже и правда мой косяк! Тут я просто описался (очевидно ведь, что я описывал работу `char`, а не `byte`) и странно, что никто этого не заметил раньше (включая меня).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Можете подсказать, почему сделали именно так, что в пул интов входят цифры только из диапазона Byte(-128-127)? И ещё один вопрос, существуют ли такие же пулы для других классов-оберток (Double, Float итд), и если нет то почему? Заранее спасибо. Ваш пост был полезен для меня!

Comment: @Aleksei 1) Размер и диапазон пула для Integer, скорее всего, выбран на основе статистики использования чисел класса, а также из соображений эффективность-стоимость пула данного размера, т.е. делать больше не настолько эффективно с точки зрения юзабилити, но при этом сильно повысит объем оперативной памяти, занимаемый пулом.
2) Точно не отвечу на ваш вопрос, но для чисел типа Double и Float весьма проблематично зарезервировать некоторый диапазон. Например, для чисел с плавающей точкой охватить диапазон [-127.0, 128.0] довольно сложно, дорого и малоэффективно (вероятность коллизий минимальна).

Comment: @Aleksei, у меня, наконец-то, дошли руки до обновления статьи. Теперь в ней, в частности, отражена информация касательно вашего второго вопроса.