# Разница между String и new String?

Tags: java, android, строки

В чем отличие `String a;` от `String a = new String();`

Answer (score 25):

[Согласно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499068/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-string-%D0%B8-new-string/499071?noredirect=1#comment593945_499071) @Pavel Parshin, в первом случае переменная `a` не инициализирована (она не равна даже `null`). Ее дальнейшее использование невозможно, иначе произойдет ошибка компиляции `error: variable a might not have been initialized`. [Пример](https://ideone.com/cn6cCg).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во втором случае, согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812690/3212712), создаётся новый объект типа `String` с пустой строкой внутри `""`

```
Sting a;
TextUtils.isEmpty(a); //ошибка компиляции - переменная не инициализирована.
a = new String();
TextUtils.isEmpty(a); //true
```

Comment: Не совсем верно. В первом случае переменная `a` не инициализирована (она не равна даже `null`). Ее дальнейшее использование невозможно, иначе произойдет ошибка компиляции error: variable a might not have been initialized. https://ideone.com/cn6cCg

Comment: @PavelParshin, вы правы. Я обновил ответ вашим комментарием.

Comment: Ну а если я напишу `String a = "";` и `String a = new String();` Тогда в чем будет разница?

Comment: @MaximPro, тут много тонкостей. Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496081/17609) про сравнение строк

Comment: когда вы пишете String a = new String(); то создается всегда новый объект.
Если написать String a = "Привет"; и String b = "Привет"; 
и сранить ссылки a==b то результат будет тру. Ссылки указывают на один объект. при String b = "Привет";  проверяется есть ли такая строка в пуле строк и если есть возвращается ссылка на нее

Answer (score 10):

Выше даны хорошие ответы, но если не понятно, то `String` - название класса, `String a;` - создание указателя на переменную класса `String`, он говорит нам, что по этому указателю будет доступна переменная этого класса, но пока это только указатель, который ни на что конкретное не указывает. `new String()` - это создание конкретного объекта в памяти, под который отводится место, и для доступа к которому может использоваться тот же указатель `а`, таким образом данная конструкция `String a = new String();` говорит нам, что указатель `а` будет указывать на этот конкретный объект в памяти `new String()`.

Answer (score 2):

При написании `String b` - вы просто создаёте переменную `b`, которая является ссылкой на объект типа `string` (но пока что она ни на что не указывает).

Когда вы пишите `String b = "Hello world"`, вы инициализируете объект сразу же, фактически, подставляется `new`. И присваиваете нашей ссылке `b` ссылку на этот объект.