# Строковая переменная с одинаковым значениям в двух случаях обрабатывается по разному. Почему?

Tags: java

Почему этот код вызывает блок if?

```
String word = "";
String push  = "push";
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    word = push;
    if (word == "push")
    {
        n = 3;
        push(n);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

А этот код нет, хотя через дебаггер проверял что там, что там "word" переменная принимает значение "push".

```
String word = "";
String push  = "push";
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    word = s.nextLine();
    if (word == "push")
    {
        n = 3;
        push(n);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: String pool - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings это по первому, по второму вам уже ответили

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В чем заключается проблема:**

Вы сравниваете строки посредством оператора `==`, который просто сравнивает на равенство ссылки на объекты, а не их содержимое (за исключением примитивов).

Ссылки на объекты не равны из-за интернирования строк (т.е. из-за использования `String pool`). В вашем случае строки, получающиеся сложением/присваиванием констант, вычисляются во время компиляции и далее строковые литералы (в одном/разных классе(ах) и в одном/разных пакете(ах)) представляют собой ссылки на один и тот же объект. Именно поэтому в первом случае ссылки оказываются равны, а во втором нет, так как метод `nextLine()` возвращает ссылку на строку не из пула.

Подробнее о том, как работает оператор `==` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80).

---

**Пути решения:**

Сравнивайте строки посредством метода `equals`:

```
if ("push".equals(word))
```

Причем, в вашем случае, метод применяйте к строковому литералу, так как если применить к переменной `word`, которая может оказаться `null`, то вылетит исключение.

---

Чисто для информации:

Также корректно отработает вариант, при котором вы принудительно засунете второй объект в пул посредством метода `intern`

```
if ("push" == word.intern())
```

Тот факт, что данный метод отработает корректно в вашем случае совсем не означает, что так и следует делать!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Воспользовался if (word.equals("push")) и всё заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы пытаетесь использовать `==` для проверки строк на эквивалентность и это неправильно. Используйте `equals`

Answer (score 1):

Переменные String необходимо сравнивать методом equals

```
if (word.equals("push"))
```

Во втором случае код работает чисто случайно, т.к. совпадают адреса объектов

```
String word = "";
String push  = "push"; //push указывает на объект String в памяти, содержащий символы "push" 
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    word = push; //word теперь указывает на тот же самый объект
    word = s.nextLine(); //создается новый обект String в другом участке памяти и wodr указывает на него
    if (word == "push") //проверка, указывает ли word на первоначальный String из инициализации push
    {
        n = 3;
        push(n);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```