# чем отличается число от строки в Java?

Tags: java, android

Чем отличается число от строки в Java?

Answer (score 12):

Строка не является примитивным типом данных в отличие от чисел. Строка - это объект (`class String extends Object`), ООП-обёртка над массивом примитивов типа `char`. Их можно получить вызовом метода `toCharArray()`:

```
char[] chars = "chars".toCharArray();
```

Все числа же - [примитивные типы данных](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Они предназначены для хранения различных числовых значений. Есть целые - `short` (2 байта), `int` (4 байта) и `long` (8 байт); есть дробные - `float` (4 байт) и `double` (8 байт).

```
short s = 0;
int i = 0;
long l = 0L;
float f = 0.0f;
double d = 0.0d;
```

Некоторые строки можно прочитать как числа с помощью специальных методов.

```
Integer.parseInt("123") == 123;
Float.parseFloat("123.0") == 123.0;
// Нельзя, вызовет исключение
//Integer.parseInt("abcdef");
```

Все числа можно представить в строковом виде вызовом статических методов классов-обёрток.

```
Integer.toString(123) == "123";
Float.toString(123.0) == "123.0";
```

Даже если в строках записано что-то, представимое как числа, их нельзя складывать как числа. Вместо этого произойдет конкатенация (объединение) строк:

```
"123" + "456" == "123456";
```

Сначала нужно преобразовать в числа.

```
Integer.parseInt("123") + Integer.parseInt("456") == 579;
```

**Важно**

Строки это объекты, поэтому их сравнивать надо аккуратно. Просто `==` не всегда будет работать так как вы можете ожидать:

1. [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417406/17609)
2. [Как работает оператор ==](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496081/17609)

Comment: Эм... Строка не является примитивом и по ссылке тоже не помянута в списке примитивов. Строка - это объект, ООП-обёртка над массивом примитивов типа `char`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, верно) поправите?

Comment: Поправил) Плюс в яве строки в двойных кавычках пишутся) Ещё ссылок немного полезных добавил.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо! Кавычки - это я к Python уже привык. )

Answer (score -2):

Ну как, - это разные типы данных, которые хранятся в памяти.

Строка является текстом - структура данных, ряд слов, букв или иных знаков - символов заключенные в ковычки.

А число - это величина с которой начинается счет или расчет математических операций, также бывают категории и подкатегории чисел, разряды, множества и многое другое.