# Не проверяются все условия в операторе if

Tags: java

При создании записи в таблице создал проверку на наличие уже существующей записи, но она не срабатывает, при дебаге выяснил, что проверяется только первое условие, в чем причина, ошибок не выдает, да и условия вроде заданы верно.

```
    public Students createStudent(String Firstname,String Lastname, String Group) throws Exception {
        try {
            begin();
            Students students = new Students(Firstname,Lastname,Group);
            List studentList = getSession().createQuery("from Students ").list();
            for(Iterator iterator= studentList.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
                Students stud = (Students) iterator.next();
                if (students.getFirstName()==stud.getFirstName()&&students.getLastName()==stud.getLastName()&&students.getGroup()==stud.getGroup()){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, but this student is already exist");
                    rollback();
                    close();
                }
            }
            getSession().save(students);
            commit();
            close();
            return students;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            rollback();
            throw new Exception("Could not create student " + " ", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (students.getFirstName() == stud.getFirstName() && students.getLastName() == stud.getLastName() && students.getGroup() == stud.getGroup())
```

В этом условии вы сравниваете объекты на равенство их указателей. Вам нужно использовать для сравнения метод `equals`.

[Более подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080).