# @PathVariable Исползование как аргумент функции

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Java. Spring-boot. Controller.

**WeatherController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/{city}/{service}")
    public JSONObject getCityName(@PathVariable final String city, @PathVariable final String service) throws IOException, ParseException {

        String openWeatherJson = getWeatherJson(city, service);
        String weatherStackJson = getWeatherJson(city, service);
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        if (service == "1"){
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(openWeatherJson);
            return json;
        }else{
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(weatherStackJson);
            return json;
        }
```

Проблема в том, что **@PathVariable final String city** ведет себя предсказуемо, и в функцию **getWeatherJson()** на вход приходит ожидаемы параметр.

НО **@PathVariable final String service** ведет себя странно.... Проверяю, что приходит в String service -> приходит верное значение либо "1" либо "2" (неважно) но ни в функции **getWeatherJson()** не в **if()** это значение либо не подставляется, либо не срабатывает как ожидалось.

Проверка показала. При наборе в адресной строке **/api/Moscow/1**. **"Moscow"** - определяется и работает предсказуемо. **"1"** - не работает не в функции не в **if**'e. **If** уходит в ветку **else**

Понятия не имею, почему так происходит.
Прошу помощи комрады.

Comment: `"1".equals(service)` нужно сравнивать по значению, а не по ссылке

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80/496081#496081  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java/417406#417406

Comment: Ну ёмаё.... Точно! Как я упустил этот момент! Спасибо!