# Не работает return, при передачи данных s = " " программа должна вернуть 0 и остановить программу, но почему то работа продолжается

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
        if(s == " ") {
            return 0;
        }
        String[] str = s.split(" ");
        return str[str.length - 1].length();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнивать строки в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)

Comment: @yashhhamaru0. если вас устраивает предоставленный ответ, то просьба отметить его (галочкой), чтобы вопрос не попадал в список "нерешенных" (без принятого ответа).

Answer (score 5):

**Краткий ответ:**

В java оператор `==` сравнивает лишь ссылки на объекты, а не их значения.

Чтобы добиться желаемого результата вам следует воспользоваться методом `equals()`:

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
        if (" ".equals(s)) {
            return 0;
        }
        String[] str = s.split(" ");
        return str[str.length - 1].length();
    }
}
```

**Подробное разъяснение:**

Описание особенностей работы с оператором `==` смотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496080/200756).