# Как сделать сравнение в java

Tags: java, if

Мне нужно сравнить 2 переменных, это

```
public static double version = 1.4;
public static double lastversion;

static {
    try {
        lastversion = BankHelper.getVersion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lastversion = version;
    }
}
```

и есть код который их использует

```
if (version <= lastversion)
{
    String BANK_DOWNLOAD_UPDATE = BANK_API_URL + "MWBank-" + lastversion + ".jar";

    MWBank.PL.getLogger().info("§aNew update founded! starting updating.... §6Download url: " + BANK_DOWNLOAD_UPDATE);
    PL.getPluginLoader().disablePlugin(PL);
    downloadUpdate(BANK_DOWNLOAD_UPDATE);
    MWBank.PL.getLogger().info("§aUpdated successfully, reloading server ....");
    Bukkit.getServer().reload();
}
```

Так вот, когда `version` и `lastversion` одинаковые (например, 1.4 и 1.4), то код в `if` всё равно выполняется.

Как сделать так, чтобы код в `if` выполнялся только тогда, когда `lastversion` больше `version`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496081/179763

Comment: @tym32167 там достаточно своеобразные ответы, но нету ответа (или не нашёл) на конкретно на мой вопрос

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос начинается там с заголовка "Сравнение вещественных примитивов"

Comment: В том ответе есть неточности.  Код в `if` выполняется потому что `1.4 <= 1.4` -> `true`, `1.4 < 1.4` -> `false`.

Comment: *Бурчание*: надо учить язык по учебнику. От дёрганья примеров из Сети без понимания их сути пользы мало. В итоге вы работаете со "взрослым" кодом, а не понимаете "детские" конструкции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Как сделать так, чтобы код в `if` выполнялся только тогда, когда `lastversion` больше `version`?*

Конкретно в данном случае должна помочь замена нестрогого сравнения `<=` на строгое:

```
if (version < lastversion) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Однако, использование `double` для хранения информации о версии *в общем случае* выглядит не слишком корректным, так как обычно версия содержит больше двух полей.

Более детальное сравнение версий описано [по ссылке](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-versions):

- С использованием класса [ComparableVersion](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html) из `maven artifact`
- C использованием класса [VersionNumber](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/util/VersionNumber.java) из `gradle-core`
- C использованием класса [Version](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Version.html) из библиотеки `jackson-core` и др.