# Почему в equals несколько return?

Tags: java, сравнение, equals

Для класса `Person` со строковыми полями `firstName` и `lastName` общий вариант для реализации `equals`:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // self check
    if (this == o)return true; //1
    // null check
    if (o == null) return false; //2
    // type check and cast
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; //3
    Person person = (Person) o;
    // field comparison
    return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) //4
        && Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
}
```

Почему в одном методе перед основным (4)return еще три return? Смысл первого return - если ссылка на разные объекты одна и та же, то они равны. Зачем тогда в конце основной return //4?

Например, упрощу метод для понимания и на выходе получу 4. Зачем нужны первые 3 return?

```java
public int test(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return 1; //Рефлексивность
    if (o == null) return 2;//Неравенство с null
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return 3; //симметричность
    
    return 4;
}
```

Какие поля в классе:

```
public class MyClass {
    double a;
    Object b;
    private int c; //не участвует в сравнении
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass test1 = new MyClass();
        test1.a = 3.2;
        test1.b = new String("Sек");
        MyClass test2 = new MyClass();
        System.out.println();
        test2.a = 3.2;
        test2.b = new String("Sек");
        //  System.out.println(test1.equals(test2));
        System.out.println(test1.test(test2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true; //Рефлексивность
        if (o == null) return false;//Неравенство с null
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false; //симметричность
        MyClass other = (MyClass) o;
        //Симметричность, транзитивность
        return other.a == this.a && (this.b == null && other.b == null || this.b.equals(other.b));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Зачем тогда в конце основной return"* --- потому что это могут быть два разных объекта, ссылающихся на разную область памяти, но при этом по всем параметрам они идентичны (например по фамилии и имени)

Comment: Это я понимаю. Я не понимаю почему 3 return перед 4 основным. Почему тогда в 4 return  все сразу не проверить? И в первых 3 с условиями return как учитывается до 4 return? Или в одну переменную общую boolean положить и поочередно проверять, записывая все 3 return.

Comment: Как будет называться одна общая переменная где будут все эти проверки?

Comment: В целом никто не запрещает всё в одном условии прописать, логически отделив все условия отдельными строками, чтобы было легкочитаемо......главное ЧИТАЕМО

Comment: Добавила пример и по итогу выдает 4 и первые 3 return идут лесом. Вопрос. Для чего они нужны? Если даже в IDEA автоматом создаются 2 return + 1 на выходе.

Comment: И что дают все эти цыфры разработчикам? Как я, не знающий систему, должен понять, что значит цифра 3?

Comment: Это к тому , что какие бы данные не были в первых 3 return верется все равно последний return из метода(4)

Comment: нет... с чего бы вернуться проверке №4  если вдруг будет  `this == o` ?

Comment: Попробуйте удалить последний 4 return - будет ошибка. Поэтому он и срабатывает

Comment: или с чего бы вернуться проверке №4  если на вход передан null?

Comment: у вас ошибка потому, что вы что-то делаете не так, и не ясно что у вас там за ошибка и какими данными оперируете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не запрещает переопределить метод `equals` "по-своему", оставив в нём базовую проверку и вынося проверку полей в отдельный *защищённый* метод:

```java
public class Foo {
    private int bar;
    private String baz;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return this == that || (that != null && getClass() == that.getClass() && isEqual((Foo) that));
    }

    // Здесь that гарантированно не совпадает с this, НЕ null и имеет нужный класс
    protected boolean isEqual(Foo that) {
        return bar == that.bar && Objects.equals(baz, that.baz);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bar, baz);
    }
}
```

Насколько при этом возрастает *читабельность* кода, дело вкуса, так как кто-то любит однострочники, а кто-то -- явные ранние условия выхода.

---

Более того, в некоторых случаях (например, когда у класса `Foo` нет наследников) допустимо использовать *классическую проверку* при помощи `instanceof` - тогда можно убрать проверку на `null`:

```java
public final class Foo {  // наследников не будет
    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        return this == that || (that instanceof Foo && isEqual((Foo) that));
    }

    // ...
}
```

В таком случае важно, чтобы обеспечивалась симметричность при сравнении `x.equals(y) == y.equals(x)`.

---

Есть также несколько замечаний по поводу реализации сравнения в классе `MyClass` в вопросе:

```java
double a;
Object b;
```

- Сравнивать `double` при помощи `==` можно только для литералов, в общем же случае такой способ не рекомендуется; если хотя бы одно из чисел вычисляется, сравнение должно выполняться с [некоторой заданной точностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496081/386633)
- Для сравнения полей `b` как раз и нужно использовать стандартный метод `Objects.equals`

Comment: Спасибо.Понятно.Крутое объяснение.

Comment: @svil Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый

Comment: @NowhereMan у меня не отобразилось :)

Comment: В методе `equals` не может быть приближенного сравнения double. Только точное. Класс с приближенным сравнением приведёт к ошибкам если объект храниться в контейнере.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, не совсем понял, что имеется в виду под хранением в контейнере.  Известно, что точное сравнение проблематично: `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3`.

Comment: А приближенное равенство нарушит требование транзитивности: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: `x + eps == x`, `x - eps == x`, `x + eps != x - eps`?

Comment: Да, именно. И это никак не поправить.

Answer (score 0):

Первый `return` (`if (this == o) return true;`) не нужен. Во всех учебниках он есть. Он экономит время если объект сравнивается сам с собой. И он тратит время зря, если сравниваются два разных объекта. Можно показать, что суммарно времени тратится больше чем выигрывается. Этот оператор можно и нужно убрать.

Второй `return` (`if (o == null) return false;`) необходим, так как `equals` обязан правильно обрабатывать нулевые ссылки. Если не будет этого оператора, нулевая ссылка `o` приведёт к исключению дальше.

Третий `return` (`if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;`) нужен чтобы объекты разных типов не оказались равны друг-другу. Можно вообразить ситуацию когда равенство объектов разных типов полезно, но это очень специальная ситуация. Если этой проверки не будет, то приведение из `Object` в `MyClass` ниже по коду может выбросить исключение.

Четвёртый `return` выполняет всю полезную работу по сравнению объектов.

Требования к реализации можно найти в [документации по Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

**P.S.** Можно считать что второй и третий операторы проверяют равенство типов. Четвёртый проверяет равенство значений.